# How do I install Oauth2 install on windows (multiple errors)

Tags: python, import, installation, package

This is my first time playing with python on a computer instead of using online modules. I'm trying to install Oath2 but the web searches I've found have a number of different ways of doing it and they each seem to present their own error when I try it.

One way I've seen is by using a command line link in this thread:

```
easy_install pywhois
```

or

```
easy_install oauth2
```

[Installing a Python module in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116986/installing-a-python-module-in-windows)

That returns an invalid syntax error.

Another way I tried was to download the tz file and move it into the site-packages folder and then run:

```
import oath2
```

[typo, I used "oauth2" in the actual command]

That also returns an invalid syntax error.

I've been combing through the threads here and other places and I just can't seem to crack this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could it be that you should be doing

```
import oauth2
```

and not

```
import oath2
```

You could alternatively use [activestate](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) python which has a lot of built-in modules, and then install any extra ones like oauth2 using the command-line command:

```
pip install oauth2
```

or

```
pypm install oauth2
```

Another way of getting it would be to download [the tarball](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2/), unzip it, open a command line, change directories to the unzipped folder, and run

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I made a typo in writing this post, on the command line I wrote "auth2" I fixed my post to reflect that.

I thought I attempted your last suggestion. I have downloaded the tarball file and unzipped it but when I try that "python setup.py install" I get:
"Python is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: That means that you do not have python set in your PATH environment variable. 

If you are on windows, you need to follow the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7). Alternatively, you can just append C:\path_to_your_python_folder to the system's PATH variable

Answer (score 2):

While I tried to install oauth2 I received a syntax error as well.
The error code was:

```
File "setup.py", line 18 
print "unable to find version in %s" %(VERSIONFILE,)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My fix was, to add the missing brackets in the print statement.

```
print("unable to find version in %s" %(VERSIONFILE,))
```

That was it. I hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Python 3 make sure print in the setup.py has correct syntax. 
If there is error like:

```
 File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Neeraj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Neeraj\oauth2\setup.py", line 18
        print "unable to find version in %s" % (VERSIONFILE,)
```

Change it to reflect the following

```
print ("unable to find version in %s" % (VERSIONFILE,))
```